# The data returned from Angular2 RC3 http service is undefined

Tags: angular

I have setup a quite simple web project to learn Angular2 RC3 (TypeScript). I do not have a backend at the moment and try to load several images from a JSON file with an HTTP GET request.

I have followed the official documentation on creating services and everything runs without exceptions or errors. However, the data returned from my service is always undefined despite that the HTTP GET request is completed successfully and I can see the response data in Firebug. Following is what I have done so far...

***images.json*** file:

```
[
    {
      "description": "image1",
      "file": "image1.jpeg"
    },
    {
      "description": "image2",
      "file": "image2.jpeg"
    },
    {
      "description": "image3",
      "file": "image3.jpeg"
    }
]
```

The part of the service responsible for loading the JSON file looks like this:

```
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
....
constructor(private http: Http) {}

getImages(imagesUrl) : Promise<Image[]> {
    return this.http.get(imagesUrl)
            .toPromise()
            .then(response => response.json().data)
            .catch(this.handleError);
};
```

The Image is a simple class:

```
export class Image {
    description : string;
    file : string;
}
```

The component that uses the service looks in part like this:

```
...
@Component({
...
providers : [ ImageService ]
...
})
constructor(private imageService : ImageService) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.imageService.getImages(this.imageSrcDir + "images.json")
        .then(images => console.log(images))
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
    }
```

*console.log(images)* from above, displays **undefined**

I am quite puzzled as to what I did wrong, any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your JSON structure is an array. You're trying to acces the `data` attribute of that array. But arrays don't have any `data` attributes.

`response.json()` is your array. No need to append `.data`.

Comment: Nice catch @JBNizet! Thank you for the lightning fast reply. I totally missed this one, now it is working fine!

Answer (score 3):

The missing data attribute issue is the fundamental problem in the "Tour of Heroes" Angular2 tutorial in Part 6: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6 during the steps outlined when changing the data from a static mock to using the InMemoryDataService.

Both the getHeros() and the getHeros(id) method has this issue. Removing the '.data' part of the expression will resolve the 'undefined' result.

Answer (score 2):

Check if

```
getImages(imagesUrl) : Promise<Image[]> {
    return this.http.get(imagesUrl)
            .toPromise()
            .then(response => response.json().data)
};
```

has anything in `response.json()`. Do something like:

```
.then(response => {
  console.log(response.json());
  return response.json().data)
})
```

Comment: Thank you too Andrei for your reply! I will keep it mind for debugging. I solved my issue with @JBNizet 's answer.