# Angular2 Service Not getting data from Spring Controller

Tags: angular, spring-boot, angular2-services

I am actaully new to angular and I am working on a project which involves angular2 and Springboot.

My issue is:

1. I have made a REST controller in springboot.
2. In Angular I have injected a service in my conponent and implemented
   a call to service method inside ngOnInit.
3. Everything works fine, the call as expected goes from angular
   frontend to REST CONTROLLER of springBoot.
4. But the issue is, I get undefined in Angular. I don't get any data
   in angular.
5. I can see in Eclipse that REST controller returns data, but I don't get it in angular.
6. EVEN IF I HIT THE URL FROM BROWSER I CAN GET THE JSON ON THE BROWSER.
7. I HAVE VALIDATED THE JSON AS WELL AND IT IS CORRECT.

Below is my angular service:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Response} from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Profile } from './profile';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

@Injectable()
export class ProfileService{

private _url  =  'http://localhost:9000/profiles';

constructor(private http: Http) {}

// getProfiles(): Observable<any>{
getProfiles() : Promise<Profile[]>{
   console.log("inside service ");
       return this.http
           .get(this._url)
           .toPromise()
           .then(response => response.json().data as Profile[])
           .catch(this.handleError);
}

private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
    console.error('An error occurred', error); // for demo purposes only
    return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
}
```

Below is my angular component:

```
import { Component , ViewContainerRef ,ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core' ;
import { ProfileService } from './profile.service' ;
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Profile } from './profile';

import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms' ;
import { Overlay ,overlayConfigFactory } from 'angular2-modal' ;
import { Modal , BSModalContext } from 'angular2-modal/plugins/bootstrap';
import {CustomModalContext , ProfileCreate } from './profile-create.component' ;

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
    providers: [ProfileService , Modal]  
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
    title = 'Permission Matrix';

constructor(private _profileService : ProfileService ,  public modal : Modal){}
profiles: Profile[]; 

ngOnInit(){
    console.log("inside component ");
    this.getHeroes();
}

getHeroes(): void {
    this._profileService
        .getProfiles()
        .then(prfiles => {
          this.profiles = prfiles;
          console.log(this.profiles);
        });
}

getCreateUpdateScreen(){
    return this.modal.open(ProfileCreate, overlayConfigFactory({num1 : 2, num2 : 3 }, BSModalContext));
}
```

Below is my mapping class in angular:

```
export class Profile {
    profil_id : string ;
    profil_name_lang: string;
    profil_name_short: string;
    geschaeftsbereich: string;
    spezialberatung: string;
}
```

Below is my spring controller:

```
package permissionbackendservice.permissionmatrix.controller;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import permissionbackendservice.permissionmatrix.domain.Profile;
import permissionbackendservice.permissionmatrix.dto.ProfileDto;
import permissionbackendservice.permissionmatrix.service.ProfileService;

@RestController
public class ProfileController {

    private final ProfileService profileservice;            

    @Autowired
    ProfileController(ProfileService profileservice) {
        this.profileservice = profileservice;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/profiles")
    public List<Profile> readprofiles(){
        // This Function will fetch all the profiles in the database
        List<Profile> profileList = null ;                       
        try {
            profileList = profileservice.readProfiles();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return profileList ; 
    }

    // function to delete an existing profiles
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST ,value = "/deleteprofile" )
    public void deleteProfile(@RequestBody List<Profile> profile){                    
        try {
            profileservice.deleteProfile(profile);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }                       
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST ,value = "/saveprofile")
    public void addProfile(@RequestBody Profile profile){ // this function is for creating new profile
        profileservice.addProfile(profile);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST ,value = "/updateprofile")
    public void updateProfile(@RequestBody Profile profile){  // this function is for updating new profile
        profileservice.updateProfile(profile);
    }

    /*
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/saveprofile") // function to both add and update profiles in database 
    public void saveProfile(@RequestParam(value = "profilNameLang") String profileNameLang, @RequestParam(value = "profilNameShort") String  profileNameShort , @RequestParam(value = "geschaeftsbereich") String geschaeftsbereich, @RequestParam(value = "profileId") String  profileId) {
        // In this function control will handled in two ways .If the profileId is null then it means its an addition of new profile as in this case profile id
        // will be generated in code and not as an user input ,otherwise if the profile id is not null then its a case  of update .
        if(profileId == null || profileId.isEmpty()){
                                               profileservice.addProfile(profileNameLang, geschaeftsbereich, profileNameShort);
        } else {
            profileservice.updateProfile(profileNameLang, geschaeftsbereich, profileNameShort, profileId);
        }                       
    }            
    */          
}
```

Comment: you've posted the service twice and haven't posted component code

Comment: @deezg updated ,,,with component

Comment: Found the solution on this post ...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38164454/the-data-returned-from-angular2-rc3-http-service-is-undefined